# Proof that the set is closed in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

$d=3$ so $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | -1/2 \leq \cos(yz)\leq f(x^2+y^2,xyz) \}$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is some fixed continuous function.

Attempt:
Let $a_n=(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ then $a_n \to (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then we say

$x_n \to y$

$y_n \to y$

$z_n \to z$

Since $f(x,y,z)= \cos(yz)$ is continuous for all $y,z$ and the set contains its limit points, it follows that the set is closed.

(please be gentle I'm very bad at topology so if someone could guide me in the right direction it would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is closed because it is the intersection of two closed sets:

- $S_1=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\,\middle|\,-\frac12\leqslant\cos(yz)\right\}$;
- $S_2=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\,\middle|\,\cos(yz)\leqslant f(x^2+y^2,xyz)\right\}$.

The set $S_1$ is closed because $S_1=h^{-1}\left(\left[-\frac12,\infty\right)\right)$, where $h(x,y,z)=\cos(yz)$. The set $S_2$ is closed for a similar reason.

Concerning your approach, I do not understand what you mean when you say “Since $f(x,y,z)= \cos(yz)$ is continuous”.